# infinite loop to keep consuming queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'm comsuming data from a queue to process. My goal is to have the data constantly processing and to not have errors crash the app so I log exceptions and try to let the program keep running.  To do this I nested the cosume statement within a infinite loop but it doesn't seem to be working. Often I'll come to the program and see it says "[x] Done" and waiting while I can see there is a ton of data in the queue.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)
    doWork(body)
    print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='dataProcessingQueue')
while True:
    try:
        channel.start_consuming()
    except:
        time.sleep(10)
```

What am I doing wrong? If my queue has 3000 entries, this will work for 10-15% then for some reason just hangs.  Am I doing something wrong with my while loop?

Comment: Why don't you remove the try except so you can see what exception it throws?

Comment: logging exceptions is a grand idea, but also, shouldn't the try/except be in the callback?

Comment: @tdelaney How would I approach that? I used to get exceptions for the start consuming. Should I wrap everything in the callback with a try/except?

Comment: @user3557327 I simplified my code a bit to post but in my real code there is logging/alerting built into the except statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do your error handling in the callback. I'm not sure whether its even legal to call start_consuming() again after an error (its internal state could be in some error condition). And you should log the errors you get so that you know whats happening and can refine the exception handler to only catch recoverable errors. I couldn't test this so pardon any minor errors.

```
import logging
import traceback

# NOTE: Just a simple logging config here, you can get fancier
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    logger = logging.getLogger('callback')
    try:
        logger.info(" [x] Received %r" % (body,))
        doWork(body)
        logger.info(" [x] Done")
    except Exception, e:
        # get granular over time as you learn what
        # errors you get because some things like
        # SyntaxError should not be dropped
        logger.error("Exception %s: %s" %(type(e),e))
        logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        # set to always ack... even on failure
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='dataProcessingQueue')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: Thanks tdelaney. I'll test but I thought I needed a while loop to keep it going in the event of a error. is that needed if I catch exceptions within the callback?

Comment: I don't know rabbitmq specifically, but that's usually how its done. There might be other issues, like how the ack is handled (i'm putting in an edit to always ack) or whether rabbitmq has other recovery mechanisms for callbacks. But restarting the message loop is usually not the way these things are handled. Its a delegation of responsibility if nothing else. The thing that starts the loop shouldn't have to know about how to recover callback errors.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the RabbitMQ here. If so, this is what you have to do:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)
    doWork(body)
    print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='dataProcessingQueue')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Yes, no while True loop to wrap the start_consuming function.'

Reference
[RabbitMQ Tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)

Comment: He's trying to handle exceptions coming from start_consuming by restarting the operation, hence the while. If you think there is a better way, great. But simply removing the error handling is not a fix.

Comment: I agree with @tdelaney I orginally used the setup in that exact tutorial but everytime there would be a error in my doWork process, it would crash. I want it to keep processing regardless of what happens.